# enumitem: multiline label with text following label

Tags: labels, enumitem

How can I make a multi-line description label with the description following the label instead of under the label, on a new line?

I currently use:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
:
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=0em}
:
\begin{description}
  \item [{\parbox[t]{1\linewidth}{Optimization of molecular methods and
  statistical procedures for forensic fingerprinting of microbial
  soil communities}}]
  description of this item
\end{description}
```

Which gives me multiline but (of course) the text comes on a new line underneath the label.

Desired result is:

**Optimization of molecular methods and statistical procedures for forensic fingerprinting of microbial soil communities** description of this item

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Would you mind posting a fully compilable, albeit minimal, document?

Comment: Isn't it what style `sameline` does?

Comment: @ChristophFrings Thanks, that does the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Christoph Frings says, this partly what `style=sameline` does. You are also working too hard in that you do not need to put the label into a `\parbox`, as the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package will take care of this for you. In fact, using the `\parbox` *forces* the line break that you don't want!

With these two changes your MWE produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\setlist[description]{leftmargin=0em,style=sameline}
\begin{description}
  \item [Optimization of molecular methods and statistical procedures
  for forensic fingerprinting of microbial soil communities]
  description of this item
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnBokma The normal way to thank is to give a green tick:)

Comment: done, apologies for my n00b (ab)use of stackexchange (first post). Will read up later this week to avoid such mishaps in the future.